# How can I change this code to work without calling method

Tags: flutter, class, toast

I have this code which accepts title and return a custom version of `FlutterToast`.

```
class CustomToast {
  CustomToast(this.title);

  final String title;

  Future buildWidget() async {
    return Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: title,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    );
  }
}
```

I need to call `CustomToast('Toast1').buildWidget();` to make it work. How to convert the `CustomToast` so that I can use `CustomToast.buildWidget('Toast1')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    class CustomToast {

// pass the value into buildwidget method and make the method static
 static Future buildWidget(String title) async {
    return Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: title,
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0,
    );
  }
}
```